# Loop the code till the cell is empty in excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops, automation, range

I stuck with this problem:
I have this code and it works but I struggle now.
I want the loop this whole code till in `Table1` the cell `D1` is empty.

```
 Sub strule()
 
    Dim myCellRange As Range
 

   Worksheets("Table1").Select                                         

 Code = Range("D1")

   Wert = Range("E10")

    Worksheets("Table2").Select
    Worksheets("Table2").Range("A1").Select
      
      lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                   
  Range("A" & lMaxRows).Select


    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select                                         
    ActiveCell.Value = Code
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Wert
    
 
    Sheets("Table1").Select                                         '
    Rows("1:10").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


End Sub
```

Comment: sry I dont know why it looks like that when i post it

Comment: Not understanding what you want to loop - copy `D1` and `E10` from `Table1` worksheet, add in columns A:B at bottom of data on `Table2` worksheet, delete rows 1:10 in `Table1` worksheet.  That final line that deletes rows 1:10 in `Table1` so if you were to loop the second time would find cell D1 empty - unless there's data below rows 1:10 but you don't explain that.

Comment: Post some sample data so we can see what the data in `Table1` looks like. AS Darren has mentioned, unless there is more data below row 10, D1 would be empty on the 2nd iteration of a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a guess at what you want... could be completely wrong though.

First of all your original code with all the selecting & activating removed:

```
Sub strule()
    
    Dim WrkSht1 As Worksheet
    Set WrkSht1 = Worksheets("Table1")
    'Worksheets("Table1").Select

    Dim Code As String
    Code = WrkSht1.Range("D1")

    Dim Wert As String
    Wert = WrkSht1.Range("E10")

    Dim WrkSht2 As Worksheet
    Set WrkSht2 = Worksheets("Table2")
    'Worksheets("Table2").Select
    'Worksheets("Table2").Range("A1").Select
      
    Dim lMaxRows As Long
    lMaxRows = WrkSht2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    WrkSht2.Cells(lMaxRows + 1, 1) = Code 'Lastrow+1 in column A.
    WrkSht2.Cells(lMaxRows + 1, 2) = Wert 'Lastrow+1 in column B.
    'Range("A" & lMaxRows).Select
    'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    'ActiveCell.Value = Code
    'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    'ActiveCell.Value = Wert
    
    WrkSht1.Rows("1:10").Delete shift:=xlUp
    'Sheets("Table1").Select                                         '
    'Rows("1:10").Select
    'Selection.Cut
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Now what I *think* you want:

```
Sub strule1()
    
    Dim WrkSht1 As Worksheet
    Set WrkSht1 = Worksheets("Table1")
    
    Dim WrkSht2 As Worksheet
    Set WrkSht2 = Worksheets("Table2")
    
    Dim lLastRow1 As Long
    lLastRow1 = WrkSht1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim x As Long
    Dim lLastRow2 As Long
    Dim Code As String
    Dim Wert As String
    For x = 1 To lLastRow1 Step 10
        Code = WrkSht1.Cells(x, 4)      'Loop 1 grabs from row 1, loop 2 from row 11
        Wert = WrkSht1.Cells(x + 9, 5)  'Loop 1 grabs from row 10, loop 2 from row 20
        
        lLastRow2 = WrkSht2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        WrkSht2.Cells(lLastRow2 + 1, 1) = Code 'Lastrow+1 in column A.
        WrkSht2.Cells(lLastRow2 + 1, 2) = Wert 'Lastrow+1 in column B.
    Next x

    WrkSht1.Rows("1:" & x).Delete shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry to nit-pick but `Rows.Count` aren't qualified throughout the code.

Comment: @SamuelEverson Yeah, I know.  Only really matters if you're mixing up between Excel 2003 & Excel 2007+ though.  All worksheets in the workbook should have the same number of rows so didn't bother qualifying it.

Comment: I always like to believe the OP has a rouge sheet with 16 rows on it and it's always the ActiveSheet when running their code, however I did think of exactly your response as I commented.

Comment: I'm actually very interested in how to make sheets with only 16 rows. Every tutorial i find just says to "delete them" which just shifts everything up and makes a blank row. How can I actually limit the sheet size in Excel?